# Testing for differences in vegetation cover

Tags: proportion, biostatistics

I'm working on an analysis of vegetation where the idea is to compare the percent cover of different plant types (e.g., oaks) between two ecosystems. The way I measured percent cover was to do a line transect, where I took 41 observations at regular intervals along a transect, noting what sort of plant was present at each point.

The trouble I'm having is with how I should test for differences between the two ecosystems. A binomial test (e.g., oak vs. non-oak) or a contingency test (e.g., chi-square to compare the distribution of vegetation types) doesn't seem appropriate. Let's say I took 10 transects in each ecosystem. That would leave me with 41*10=410 "observations," but these are obviously not independent due to the fact that each group of 41 came from a single transect.

Would a mixed-effects logistic regression model be the way to go? Here's how I would envision that:

- Independent variable: Categorical, Ecosystem A or B?
- Dependent variable: Probability of oak (e.g.)
- Random effects variable: Transect number

If it seems like this is appropriate, I'd need a hint as to how to perform that analysis in R. I've used nlme for mixed-effects linear models before, but can it handle logistic regression?

Alternatively, is this an instance where the arcsine transformation of proportions for use in a comparison-of-means test (e.g., t-test) actually makes sense?

Or am I just thinking about this too hard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How were the transects chosen?  Were any aspects of them, such as origin or orientation, randomized?

Comment: Origin was randomized, but all had the same orientation.

Comment: Steven Thompson [describes](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470402318.html) how the [Horvitz-Thompson estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horvitz%E2%80%93Thompson_estimator) can be applied to transect samples like these.  His book is practical and accessible: I warmly recommend a look.

Answer (score 1):

Each transect is your sampling unit (since your sampling points along the transect are autocorrelated). If you calculate the proportion of points that are oak along each transect, you can compare the proportions of oak cover between the two ecosystems via a simple t-test.